# Handling encoded Server Requests

Tags: php, swift, laravel, request

an iPhone app that accesses my server sends the following request which is JSON encoded:
    http://SERVERIP/v1/aeds%3Flatitude=48.1847717939393&longitude=11.2526212725893

```
    // Generate URL Request
    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!

    // Append the path components from the result
    let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(result.path))
    print(URLRequest.URLString)

    // Create URLRequest inclunding the encoded parameters
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
    let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: result.parameters)
    encodedRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
```

So the "?" is being replaced by "%3F"

But now, my server seems to get into trouble. How do I handle this encoded request in my routing or controller to be handled correctly?

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/aeds', 'AED\APIAEDController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    // Get Latitude and Longitude from request url
    $latitude = $request["latitude"];
    $longitude = $request["longitude"];
    $aeds = new AED();

    // In no latitude and longitude is provided in request, search for all aeds
    // If latitude and longitude is set in request, search for aeds in proximity of this location information
    if(!isset($latitude) & !isset($longitude)) {
        $aeds = $aeds->getAllAEDs();
        $transformedAEDs = $this->respondWithCollection($aeds, new AEDTransformer);

        // If no aeds are found return with error
        if(!$aeds) {
            $this->setStatusCode(404)->respondWithError("Keine AED in der Datenbank");
        }

        // Add meta information and merge the arrays
        $meta = ['meta' => ['Heading 1' => 'H1', 'Heading 2' => 'H2']];
        $response = array_merge($transformedAEDs, $meta);

        return $this->setStatusCode(200)->respond($response);
    } else {
        $aeds = $this->searchAEDInRange($latitude, $longitude);
        $transformedAEDs = $this->respondWithCollection($aeds, new AEDTransformer);

        if (sizeof($aeds) == 0) {
            $this->setStatusCode(404)->respondWithError("Keine AED in der Datenbank");
        }
    }

    // Set Meta information and combine with data
    $meta = ['meta' => ['Heading 1' => 'H1', 'Heading 2' => 'H2']];
    $result = array_merge($transformedAEDs, $meta);

    return $this->setStatusCode(200)->respond($result);
}
```